# Craco - Could not resolve dependency error

Tags: create-react-app, craco

I am trying to setup TailwindCSS in my Create-React-App project and I am trying to install craco so that I need not eject my CRA

When I run the following command npm install @craco/craco, I get unable to resolve dependency tree error. Below is the detail of the error. What should I do? Thanks

```
npm install @craco/craco
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: exchange@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react-scripts@3.4.3
npm ERR! node_modules/react-scripts
npm ERR!   react-scripts@"3.4.3" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react-scripts@"^4.0.0" from @craco/craco@6.1.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@craco/craco
npm ERR!   @craco/craco@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
```

Answer (score 10):

### This works for me

```
npm install @craco/craco --save --legacy-peer-deps
```

With the below line you can also set `--legacy-peer-deps` permanently as a config option. Try to avoid this as you need to see which npm library/libraries in your project is/are having dependency issues.

```
npm config set legacy-peer-deps true
```

Answer (score 5):

I've updated my package `react-scripts` to the latest version 4.x.
by running this command :

```
npm i react-scripts@latest
```

then lo and behold, I was able to install `craco` successfully.

Answer (score 3):

Run this; it worked for me:

```
npm config set legacy-peer-deps true
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `yarn add`, it would solve this for you, you don't need to do anything for the react-scripts version.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error has to do with the dependency tree.

You have `react-scripts@3.4.3` but `@craco/craco` requires `react-scripts@4.0.0`.

Simply run `npm i react-scripts@4.0.0` and create `craco.config.js` file

Answer (score 0):

i update my react app  and then installed craco 5.05v

Answer (score 0):

In my case using `node v16.15.1` raising this error.
I resolved it by using `node v16.13.1` with fixing the version in package.json

```
  "engines": {
    "node": "16.13.1"
  },
```

You can also resolve by using `yarn` not `npm`.

Answer (score 0):

Related issue:

Didn't want to upgrade `react-scripts`
So tried downgrading craco
It worked fine:

Commands that worked fine are below:

```
npm uninstall -g craco
npm uninstall -g @craco/craco

npm i -g craco@0.0.3
npm i -g @craco/craco@6.4.3
```

package.json contents:

```
"react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
"@craco/craco": "^6.4.3",
"craco": "^0.0.3",
```

If you are changing package.json then do:

```
npm i
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated `craco-less 1.20.0` with `craco 6.4.3` and `react-scripts 4.0.3`, it worked.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@craco/craco": "^6.4.3",
    "craco-less": "^1.20.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    ...
  },
```

Answer (score -4):

```
npm install -f
```

Could help here.